# In Java, how do I sort files in a vector into 3 different vectors according to the file's last modified date?

Tags: java, sorting, file-io, vector

If I have a vector containing a number of unsorted files, how can I categorize them by their last modified date?

what I need to do is to place the files into 3 other vectors, with the last modified date of "Today", "Yesterday", and "This Week".

```
Vector<File> files;  //This vector contains all the files that need to be categorized
Vector<File> todayFiles;  //Empty
Vector<File> yesterdayFiles;  //Empty
Vector<File> weekFiles;  //Empty
```

I know I can use file.lastModified() to get the date, but it returns the date in milliseconds formatted as a long int, so I am not sure if there is an easier way to compare and group the dates without doing some intricate arithmetic work.

I am new to Java, so I have no idea how to approach this question, any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I was able to get the code to work somehow, but it is still not working properly.  This is what I have:

```
private Calendar cal;
private long todayTime;

this.cal = Calendar.getInstance();
this.cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
this.cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
this.cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
this.cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
this.cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
this.todayTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();
```

Now when I try to add them into the vector that I created, it is only grabbing files that have been modified in the PM of today's date:

```
for(int i = 0; i < this.files.size(); i++) {
    if(this.files.get(i).lastModified() >= this.todayTime) {
        this.today.add(this.files.get(i));  
    }
}
```

Is there anything that I am doing wrong?  Thank you for all the great responses by the way!

Comment: What have you tried? Please read the [faq] and [ask] to understand why your question is likely to be closed as "not a real question".

Comment: What format are the files in the vector? Are they addresses or the new `File` format?

Comment: Have a look at `Comparator` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html

Comment: Sorry if I am doing anything wrong, this is my first time posting.  The vector contains File objects, so like Vector<File> files.

Comment: You can make a `Date` out of long time like `Date modifiedDate=new Date(file.lastModified());` and then use that for your sorting.

Comment: You can create a date instance with new Date(file.lastModified()) then you can use before / after to determine in which of the vectors to put it. Hope this helps. BTW java date and calendar suck! If you don't mind the dependency use Joda Time instead.

Comment: Thank you for all the responses.  But how can I initialize today's date as a Date object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) class to get timestamps for the required dates such as today and yesterday. For example, to get today's (midnight) timestamp:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
// cal initially contains current time
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

long todayTimestamp = cal.getTimeInMillis();
```

Then you can compare this timestamp with `file.lastModified()` and put the file into the corresponding vector.

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you!  Now just one more question, if I need to "add a day" to the time stamp, how do I go about doing that elegantly without doing hard arithmetic?

Comment: Sorry I meant "subtract a day".

Comment: @user1220152: `Calendar` has an `add` method to do exactly that (negative values subtract).

Answer (score 0):

1. Implement a **Comparator** for sorting on the **lastModified**.
2. use Collections.sort to sort your objects, and iterate over them after that.
3. Use a calendar to get start and end millis of every interval you need (today, yesterday, last ween)
4. partition your sorted collection using the intervals.
5. If there is no concurrency issue, don't use Vectors, just use ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

Write a function which iterates over the list of all files and compares each item's last modified date with the known values of today, yesterday, and the range of days in the last week.  A helpful fact is that ISO 8601 date format is lexicographically comparable, so for example (untested):

```java
public static void bucketDates(List<File> inputFiles,
                               Collection<File> today,
                               Collection<File> yesterday,
                               Collection<File> lastWeek) {
  // Build date strings that match our dates of interest.
  DateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
  String strToday = fmt.format(getToday());
  String strYesterday = fmt.format(getYesterday());
  String strFirstDayOfLastWeek = fmt.format(getFDOLW());
  String strLastDayOfLastWeek = fmt.format(getLDOLW());
  // Now see which bucket each input date falls into.
  for (File f : inputFiles) {
    String lastMod = fmt.format(new Date(f.lastModified()));
    if (strToday.equals(lastMod)) {
      today.add(f);
    } else if (strYesterday.equals(lastMod)) {
      yesterday.add(f);
    } else if ((strFirstDayOfLastWeek.compareTo(lastMod) <= 0)
        && (strLastDayOfLastWeek.compareTo(lastMod) >= 0)) {
      lastWeek.add(f);
    }
  }
}
```

Note that using a date library such as [Joda-Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) would probably make the date comparisons easier (and certainly the date computation).